# Comparing long data type with varchar data in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, type-conversion, check-constraints

Consider following scenario :

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  name VARCHAR2(50),
  type LONG,
  CONSTRAINT c_type CHECK (type IN ('a',  'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))
);
```

I want to `alter constraint` c_type and add a new type in check constraint say 'g'.

Now to alter a constraint we need to drop it and recreate it, but I want to drop the constraint only if it do not contains check for type 'g'.

I checked table `user_constraints`, it contains column search_condition but problem here is the data type for column "type" is `long` which i am not able to compare with `varchar`.

How to compare the `Long` data type?

Comment: Maybe this post can give you some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918240/oracle-comparing-default-value-of-a-column

Comment: Are you going to extend or shrink the list of elements on a regular basis or it's a one time task?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Its a one time task for now, but the block to add the type is going to execute on regular basis, so for that reason I want to avoid execution of that block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem isn't that the `TYPE` column is LONG but that `SEARCH_CONDITION` of `user_constraints` is a LONG.

So you can do something similar to the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918240/oracle-comparing-default-value-of-a-column), in your case it can look like this:

```
select count(*)
from 
(SELECT XMLTYPE(
DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select SEARCH_CONDITION from user_constraints ')
).extract('//SEARCH_CONDITION/text()').getstringval() srch_cond
from dual)
where srch_cond like '%&apos;g&apos;%'
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2014/11)

Comment: '%&apos;g&apos;%' I am not getting how to put a search condition, can you please explain this?

Comment: Since I used the `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML` to convert the long into a varchar2 it was "xml escaped" so every `'` became `&apos;`. You can run only the inner query and see the results

Comment: I am executing the same on sqldeveloper but it is asking for Enter substitution value for APOS and then it gives ORA-31011: XML parsing failed error.

Comment: You can always use plsql to compare the long value with a varchar2 as well, as plsql can implicitly convert bitween the two

Answer (score 3):

As another approach, you could use a cursor - PL/SQL converts values that are of `LONG`  data type to `VARCHAR2` data type  while fetching from a cursor:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  cursor c_cursor is
    select search_condition as sc
      from user_constraints
     where constraint_name = 'C_TYPE'; 

  l_list varchar2(4000);
begin
   /* 
      As long as you are querying user_constraints data dictionary view,
      specifying constraint name
      you guarantee that the only one row will be returned.

   */
  for i in c_cursor
  loop
    l_list := i.sc;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_list);
end;
```

Result:

```
anonymous block completed
col in ('a', 'b','c','d','e','f')
```